# Error installing Ionic using npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I am new to Ionic framework. As a starter I installed cordova using npm as `npm install -g cordova` which installed 6.2.0 successfully. I got following error when installing ionic as `npm install -g ionic`.

[image]

npm: 3.10.5
node: 6.10.2

I also re-installed node, but that dint help me.
When I write ionic in cmd i get following error :

[image]

I dont know what is the issue with npm or anything else.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Steps you should do:

```
npm cache clean
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm install -g ionic
```